# Show images in view from http header

Tags: php, html, image, symfony, http-headers

I generate an image in my controller (I use Symfony2) and when I return my response with my image I get this:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=""
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

I need to show the image in my view, but if I put:

```
<img src="<?= $response ?>" />
```

The browser shows 404 error and if I use

```
<?php echo $response; ?>
```

I only get

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="example.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Date: Wed, 08 Oct 2014 14:55:24 GMT
X-Sendfile: 67902
```

I want to show te image, any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: `<img src=...` expects a URL. if `$response` contains the raw binary data of your image, then you can't just stuff that into the src attribute. Not unless you turn it into a data-uri.

Comment: Thanks Marc, but how can I convert this ray binary data to a data-uri?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Format

Answer (score 1):

You can use a route that display your image

In your controller :

```
/*
 * @Route("/getImage", name="getImage")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function testAction(Request $request, $id)
{   
    $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response();
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private');
    $response->headers->set('Content-type', 'image/jpg');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="example.jpg"');        
    $response->setContent(file_get_contents('example.jpg'));
    return $response;
```

}

In your twig template :

```
<img src="{{path('getImage')}}">
```